# TinyMCE not initializing, but no JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a VERY simple email form (for a members-only page for a private club) to send email blasts.  The code is simply:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Email Blast</h1>
<form method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="from" value="blast@club.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="to" value="blast@club.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="reply" value="from@club.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="bcc" value="Tester <test@club.com>" />

<label for="subject">Subject</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" style="width: 600px" /><br/>

<label for="message">Message</label><br/>
<textarea id="message" name="message" rows="15" cols="100" class="tinymce"></textarea><br/>

<br/><input type="submit" value="Send Email" name="submit">

</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({selector:"textarea.tinymce"});
});
</script>
```

For some reason the page simply isn't rendering the `textarea.tinymce` as I would expect, but there are no error messages in the JS Console and all the breakpoints are hit as I would expect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your `script` tag inside the `body` tag, just before closing it.

If you put anything after closing your `body` tag, the browser will ignore it.

Look at the example below - if you place the `script` tag inside the `body` tag, it works like a charm:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.2.5/tinymce.jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Email Blast</h1>
<form method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="from" value="blast@club.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="to" value="blast@club.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="reply" value="from@club.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="bcc" value="Tester <test@club.com>" />

<label for="subject">Subject</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" style="width: 600px" /><br/>

<label for="message">Message</label><br/>
<textarea id="message" name="message" rows="15" cols="100" class="tinymce"></textarea><br/>

<br/><input type="submit" value="Send Email" name="submit">

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({selector:"textarea.tinymce"});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see that it works this way when I run your snippet, but it wasn't working on my server -- until I changed the TinyMCE to match yours!  Something must be wrong with my tinymce.js file!